# Adding C# support to SCons on Mac

Tags: c#, python, scons

I found C# support for SCons (https://bitbucket.org/russel/scons_csharp/overview), but I don't know where to install (copy) the python scripts are  copied into.

I installed Scons with brew command, so I have `/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.3.4` directory on my Mac.

[image]

What should be the next step to install the C# builders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a directory `~/.scons/site_scons/site_tools`.
2. cd `~/.scons/site_scons/site_tools`
3. `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/russel/scons_csharp`

Change one line (460) from `csharp.py` (`~/.scons/site_scons/site_tools/scons_csharp/csharp.py`).

```
env['CSC']          = env.Detect('mcs') or 'csc'
```

We need this change because the default setting for compiler (`gmcs`) is outdated.

Create build file: `SConstruct`.

```
env = Environment(
   tools=['scons_csharp']
)

sources = ['Hello.cs']
prog = env.CLIProgram('myapp', sources)
```

Execute `scons -Q` to get:

```
mcs -nologo -noconfig -out:.../myapp.exe Hello.cs
```

#### References

- http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex
- http://www.scons.org/wiki/CsharpBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Please visit the index of all external SCons Tools at http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex . Under the section "Install and usage" you can find a list of search directories for each platform.

Note that, since the C# support is not a core package, it's not installed into your default SCons distribution. Instead, it's treated like a customization (decoration?) of the standard sources...hence the machine/user-specific search paths.